# Issues with email attachment, PDF and CSV

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, qlpreviewcontroller, uti

I'm working with PDF generation,it generated the PDF, viewed using `QLPreviewController`, all worked fine except mail forwarding, I have two attachments of type .pdf and .csv. I have the following issues while emailing.

- sometimes no attachments while emailing
- pdf size will be very huge when pdf contains image(10 mb for one page pdf, if it contains image)

  Problem is when testing in device,in simulator it all works fine...,
  I come to know some exporting or importing UTI associated issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408029/xcode-4-document-types-and-exported-utis)
  since I am a starter I feel difficult to  understand it, I think some UTI's I have to add somewhere.. Can anyone please help me to identify the issue and solve, please.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: iam struggling with  this for two days.. can anyone help me!

Comment: How big is your image before it is put in the PDF?

Comment: normally,  1mb size or below..

Comment: Well my only guess is that the PDF is rasterizing the whole area as an image and taking up a huge amount of space, you will have to construct the PDF in a different way.

Comment: @GradyPlayer thanks.. but my bigger issue is number one, which is not solved. And size is ok if there is no image added to pdf.

Comment: Well email is 7 bit ASCII are you encoding the attachments?

Comment: Post an example of what you are doing... The encoding is typically base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1. Attachment issue**

set mime type as text/csv instead of application/csv or image/csv. code is as shown below

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.csvFilePath]
                               mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"csvPage.csv" ]];
```

> **1. Size issue**

I struggled a lot.. at last when wrote image in jpeg format to pdf page using below code, size got reduced ten times!!

```
UIImage *lowResImage = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(plotImage, 0.02)];
```